# Bootstrap 50/50 div with "OR" box overlay in middle of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got what I thought would be a simple issue with overlaying a box in the middle of the screen over two divs that are 50/50 in width on the screen.\

What Im trying to do is overlay a simple div that will end up being an image to display the word "OR" so the user has options for registering etc.

My issue is, I cant seem to get it dead center on the page

```
.or-box{position:absolute; left:45%; top:50%; z-index:99999; border:1px solid black; height:50px; width:50px; text-align:center; padding-top:15px;}
```

I thought it would be simple, but it appears to move just out of being 50% on the page when i load it on there.

Is there something Im missing when trying to overlay a div that is absolute over two other divs?

Thanks in advance

Below is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dimmers/5fteh5tk/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same way you centered the top (A) block, but you used `top: 50%; translateY(-50%);` on the top block to center vertically. Centering horizontally is the same technique, except you use `left` and `translateX()`

```
left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5fteh5tk/6/

Answer (score 0):

this is when `left:calc(50% - 25px)` comes in handy.

```
.or-box{position:absolute; left:calc(50% - 25px); top:50%; z-index:99999; border:1px solid black; height:50px; width:50px; text-align:center; padding-top:15px;}
```